# List of genes across species (or just for humans)

Tags: database, genomes

Wondering if there is a place that has a list/table/database of all the genes in the human genome, and/or all the known genes in all the species we've studied so far. Something that contains any of this would be great.

I found [this](http://atlasgeneticsoncology.org/Indexbychrom/idxg_X.html) but not sure yet if that is just for humans and just for one chromosome. But I'd like something along those lines across species, or the closest thing to that that exists.

Comment: There are a number of sites that store genetic data. The most famous of all is probably [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle there are a LOT of these databases and depending on your specific questions you may want to look into different ones. Like already mentioned [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov) hosts basically all of the available information, however it's not always easy to find the bits you care about.

The database I personally use the most is [biomart](http://www.ensembl.org/biomart) (hosted by the ensembl consortium). It doesn't just contain all known for genes for pretty much all organisms, but is also able to link this to a ot of different information sources.
I usually access the database directly via the biomaRt R package, so I can't really say how good the actual website this. However, [this link](http://www.ensembl.org/biomart/martview/16e05b8d2506cabed40f823222b28f93) should allow you to download a table of all human genes with names, (unique) identifies & descriptions (I selected these from the 'Attributes' section).